# How to find the probability of countable infinite sets?

Tags: probability

consider the set A = {1,2,3,...n}. If all subsets of A are equally likely to be chosen, what is the probability that a randomly selected subset of  A contains 1?

Comment: How is this countably infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of subsets of A is given as

$$n(\phi(A)) = 2^{n} $$

The way I get this is that for a given subset, either an element is present or not present, and hence gives two options for each element.

Now, for subsets that include 1, that option is already taken. Hence the number of subsets would be $2^{n - 1}$ for deciding which of the remaining elements will be part of the set

Hence the probability of picking out one of these sets is

$$P= \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2}$$